# active assignment rule through visual force page?

Tags: assignment-rules

can anyone  help me with how to make assignment rule active through visualforce page .i have did this:-

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="case" extensions="Caseassignment"  action="{!assignmentactive}">

  <apex:form >

  <apex:pageblock title="new case">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
          <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save me"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageblocksection title="create new case here">
  <apex:inputField value="{!case.subject}"  required="true"/>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!case.description}" required="true"/>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!case.priority}"  />
          <apex:inputfield value="{!case.status}" />


        </apex:pageblocksection>
      </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

extension class:-

```
public class Caseassignment{



public Boolean useDefaultRule {get; set;}
public  Caseassignment(apexpages.standardcontroller  controller){

}
public void assignmentactive(){
//Fetching the assignment rules on case
AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true limit 1];

//Creating the DMLOptions for "Assign using active assignment rules" checkbox
Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= AR.id;

Case newCase = new Case() ;
//Setting the DMLOption on Case instance
newCase.setOptions(dmlOpts);
insert newCase ;
}
}
```

assignment rule is not getting fired. can anyone tell me the whole code to make an assignment rule active proper one . any help would be appreciated.

note:- allowdml:- is showing not supported and `<apex:component>` cannot be  used inside the `<apex:page>`. tried almost everything to get it active.

Answer (score 0):

`<apex:component>` can in fact be used inside of `<apex:page>` just not the definition. Once you have your VF component saved, you will reference it as `<c:componentName allowDML="true" controller="yourApexController">`

[VF Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_component.htm)

In addition, you are going to want to link the standard controller case and the one you are inserting in that piece of code.

```
public newCase {get;private set;}
public  Caseassignment(apexpages.standardcontroller  controller){
    this.newCase =(Case) controller.getRecord();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your VF page has a page action method `assignmentActive` that is trying to insert a Case before the page is rendered.

You should remove the page action attribute and

- rename the controller method `assignmentActive` to `save`. This is overriding the standardController's `save` method that your VF page was inadvertently executing.
- the renamed method should then return (presumably) a PageReference to the Case Detail page (`return new PageReference('/'+newCase.Id);`)

Then, when the command button is clicked, the Case is created with the DML Options to run assignment rules